# How set value for attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, attributes, collection, save

I have this code:

```
foreach ($skuScope as $sku)
{
    $object = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product = $object->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
}}
```

**I can get all attributes, all values, but I don’t know how to rewrite values for an attribute**

Help me, please! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this.

```
<?php


Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $product) 
{
    $attributeCode = "my_option";
    echo "\n".'updating '.$product->getSku()."...\n";
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product’)
                   ->load($product->getEntityId());
    $product->setData($attributeCode, "enter_your_value")
            ->getResource()
            ->saveAttribute($product, $attributeCode);
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: This does not fit, I need to rewrite the value of an existing attribute

Comment: Yes this is just a example of the code.